# PHP: preg_replace between "<<" and ">>"

Tags: php

Hi I want to replace the content between "<<" and ">>" with custom div class how can I do that?

I tried some regex but It didn't work.

```
$con = preg_replace ('/<<(.*?)>>/s', '<div>$1</div>', $con);
```

Comment: since you already tried some regex, can you show us what you tried? ;)

Comment: $con = preg_replace ('/<<(.*?)>>/s', '<div>$1</div>', $con);

Comment: What's the value of `$con` - I've just literally dropped this into a PHP file and it works : `echo preg_replace('/<<(.*?)>>/s', "<div>$1</div>", "<<womble>>");` - it prints out `<div>womble</div>`

Comment: Shouldn't make any odds, neither `<` or `>` are meta characters in RegExp (except for a lookbehind) so there's no reason why that shouldn't work "as-is" ... strange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would propose putting the < and > in character classes:

```
preg_replace('/[<]{2}(.*?)[>]{2}/s', '<div>$1</div>', $con);
```

Escaping them should also work

```
preg_replace('/\<\<(.*?)\>\>/s', '<div>$1</div>', $con);
```

But CC001's comment above is correct: Neither one of these is needed.